# O "new DOMParser" é mais seguro que "document.createElement"?

Tags: javascript, segurança, dom, xss

Eu criei um script pra tentar remover conteudo inseguro na hora de injetar DOM (estou usando em extensões/addons pra navegadores):

```js
var str = "<strong>Hello</strong> mundo <script src="http://site/badscript.js"></script>";
CreateDOM(str);

function RemoveAttrs(target)
{
    var attrs = target.attributes, currentAttr;
    var validAttrs = [ "href", "class", "id", "target" ];

    for (var i = attrs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentAttr = attrs[i].name;

        if (attrs[i].specified && validAttrs.indexOf(currentAttr) === -1) {
            target.removeAttribute(currentAttr);
        }

        if (
            currentAttr === "href" &&
            /^(#|javascript[:])/gi.test(target.getAttribute("href"))
        ) {
            target.parentNode.removeChild(currentAttr);
        }
    }
}

function RemoveEls(target)
{
    var current;

    //Remove elements insecure (blacklist)
    var list = target.querySelectorAll("script,link,...");

    for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        current = list[i];
        current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
    }

    //Remove insecure attributes (whitelist)
    list = target.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        RemoveAttrs(list[i]);
    }

    return target;
}

function CreateDOM(MinhaString)
{
     var tmpDom = document.createElement("div");
     tmpDom.innerHTML = MinhaString;

     tmpDom = RemoveEls(tmpDom);

     //Inject in container
     document.getElementById("container").appendChild(tmpDom);
}
```

No entanto na hora de submeter a extensão para o http://addons.opera.com o moderador analisou o meu código e me mandou esta mensagem:

> Your cleanDomString method is not safe, please replace:
>   tmpDom.innerHTML = data; with: var tmpDom = (new
>   DOMParser).parseFromString(data, "text/html").body;
>
> and remove: var tmpDom = document.createElement("div");
>
> or use:
>   https://github.com/operatester/safeResponse/blob/1.1/safeResponse.js
>
> dmichnowicz; May 30, 2016 8:46:57 AM UTC

Então mudei o código e ele ficou assim:

```js
var str = "<strong>Hello</strong> mundo <script src="http://site/badscript.js"></script>";
CreateDOM(str);

function RemoveAttrs(target)
{
    var attrs = target.attributes, currentAttr;
    var validAttrs = [ "href", "class", "id", "target" ];

    for (var i = attrs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentAttr = attrs[i].name;

        if (attrs[i].specified && validAttrs.indexOf(currentAttr) === -1) {
            target.removeAttribute(currentAttr);
        }

        if (
            currentAttr === "href" &&
            /^(#|javascript[:])/gi.test(target.getAttribute("href"))
        ) {
            target.parentNode.removeChild(currentAttr);
        }
    }
}

function RemoveEls(target)
{
    var current;

    //Remove elements insecure (blacklist)
    var list = target.querySelectorAll("script,link,...");

    for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        current = list[i];
        current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
    }

    //Remove insecure attributes (whitelist)
    list = target.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        RemoveAttrs(list[i]);
    }

    return target;
}

function CreateDOM(MyString)
{
     var tmpDom = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(MyString, "text/html").body;

     tmpDom = RemoveEls(tmpDom);

     //Inject in container
     document.getElementById("container").appendChild(tmpDom);
}
```

Tá certo fiz a mudança como pedido, mas eu fiquei sem entender aonde isto melhorou a segurança, é apenas uma curiosidade a nivel de estudo.

Qual a diferença entre ambos em questão de segurança?

Comment: Não entendo o suficiente e admito que nem li a pergunta com atenção. Mas o que pode ser mais inseguro que rodar código no cliente? :) Se há alguma insegurança nesse código, não tem o que fazer, porque mesmo que você faça certo, alguém vai e mexe nele e deixa inseguro. Eu entendo a pessoa querer deixar um código em JS mais robusto, mas mais seguro eu acho estranho (a não ser que seja Node ou algo parecido rodando em servidor, aí, claro, é diferente). neste caso específico talvez tenha sentido por rodar no próprio navegador. Em tese um *plugin* não deveria abrir brechas.

Comment: Essa resposta foi gerada automaticamente ou alguém "olhou" o seu código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atributos de eventos como `onerror`, `onload` e outras coisas são executados mesmo que o elemento DOM não seja adicionado ao corpo da página, um teste de exemplo:

```js
function createDOM(str) {
  document.createElement("div").innerHTML = str;
}
createDOM('<img src="//" onerror="alert(\'Executou mesmo sem adicionar ao document.body!\')" />');
```

Veja que não tem `appendChild` e mesmo assim `onerror` dispara o `alert()`.

Agora veja assim:

```js
function createDOM(str) {
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html").body;
}
createDOM('<img src="//" onerror="alert(\'Executado\')" />');
```

Veja não houve disparo do `alert()`.

Ou seja no momento que faço isto:

```
 var tmpDom = document.createElement("div");
 tmpDom.innerHTML = MinhaString;

 tmpDom = RemoveEls(tmpDom);
```

Antes mesmo de executar o `RemoveEls` o `innerHTML` já dispara o qualquer evento e nisto pode ocorrer o problema de segurança. Ou seja deve usar o `DOMParser`

<sub>*Fonte:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/37554728/1518921</sub>