# Como pegar o conteúdo de uma variável JavaScript, que é uma tag HTML?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho conteúdo de tag HTML:

```
<p id="horaInicial">2018-07-23 16:40:16</p>
```

dentro de uma variável JavaScript, quero saber como acessar o valor: 
2018-07-23 16:40:16 e colocar dentro de outra variável!

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Poste o trecho do html que tem a tag para facilitar.

Comment: já tentou usar `x = document.getElementById('id_da_tag').innerHTML;` ?

Comment: já tenteou `var x=document.getElementById("horaInicial").innerText`?

Comment: Não tinha visto sumir as tags, perdoe-me!

Comment: Então..
Preciso pegar diretamente da variável, porque ela é resultado de um for na página.. que pega algumas publicações (conjuntos de divs) e depois pega o conteúdo dessas divs internas..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crie um elemento que interprete como DOM e use `textContent`, assim por exemplo:

```js
var foo = '<p id="horaInicial">2018-07-23 16:40:16</p>';
var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
tmpDiv.innerHTML = foo;

var bar = tmpDiv.querySelector("#horaInicial").textContent;

console.log(bar);
```

Se por um acaso usa jQuery poderia simplesmente use o `$()` combinado com `.text()`:

> claro que importar o jQuery só para isto seria consumo desnecessário, então só o faça se já usa jQuery para outras coisas

```js
var foo = '<p id="horaInicial">2018-07-23 16:40:16</p>';

var bar = $(foo).text();

console.log(bar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Segurança no DOM contra

Vale notar que se tiver imagens ou outros resources dependendo da origem da string que contém o HTML o seu código pode se tornar inseguro (não é que ele será inseguro, são casos isolados/especificos), veja uma postagem relacionada a isto:

- [O "new DOMParser" é mais seguro que "document.createElement"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131290/3635)

Então se não tiver certeza da origem dos dados desta string, tipo puder vir de fontes externas para evitar **ataques** faça o uso de `DOMParser`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Navegadores suportados:

- IE9+
- Safari 3.2+
- Chrome
- Firefox

Exemplo:

```js
function createDOM(str) {
   return new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
}

var foo = '<p id="horaInicial">2018-07-23 16:40:16</p>';
var tmpElement = createDOM(foo);

var bar = tmpElement.querySelector("#horaInicial").textContent;

console.log(bar);
```

Se fosse jQuery teria que combinar:

```js
function createDOM(str) {
   return new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
}

var foo = '<p id="horaInicial">2018-07-23 16:40:16</p>';

var bar = $("#horaInicial", createDOM(foo)).text();

console.log(bar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Opa, fiz uso do "textContent" e consegui pegar o conteúdo. 
Já havia tentado pegar com value mas não funcionava rsrsrs

Comment: @JúniorGreco editei a resposta e deixei um detalhe sobre segurança

Comment: Ótimo, muito obrigado! ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento editei lá

Comment: Ola caro @res , se refere a sua resposta? Ou outra coisa?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função **jquery** `.text()`, que vai retornar o conteudo do elemento que desejar.

Exemplo:

```html
        <html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var conteudo = "<p id=\"horaInicial\">2018-07-23 16:40:16</p>";

    $(function () {
        var outra_variavel = $(conteudo).text();
        alert(outra_variavel);
    });
</script>
</head>

</html>
```